# Using Java 8, what is the most concise way of creating a sorted AND grouped list of Strings

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, group-by, java-8

Using Java 8, what is the most concise way of creating a sorted AND grouped list of Strings? Show the old way and the new way using Lambdas and the Collections and Streams framework.

You can show using 3rd party libraries (popular ones) for the old (or new) way.

However, I suggest that vanilla Java be used because that shows the changes that the language changes in Java 8 bring to the table for the task.

```
Input: List<String>
Output: Map<Character<List<String>>
The key of map is 'A' to 'Z'
Each list in the map are sorted.
```

It will be sorted and grouped such that ...

Given this list: "Beer", "Apple", "Banana", "Ananas", "Mango", "Blue Berry"

A `Map` will produced containing the first letter as the key. The values in the map will be a sorted `List` of all the words beginning with that key (letter):

- key: A   values: ["Ananas","Apple"]
- key: B   values: ["Banana","Beer","Blue Berry"]
- key: M   values: ["Mango"]

Comment: What do you mean by "sorted and grouped"?  How are you grouping them?  (And are third-party libraries allowed for "the old way"?)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using Java, with no help from 3rd party libraries, there is the old way and the new way. Just sorting used to be easy with Collections.sort(..).

The challenge with the old way was that a lot of code was required to group the values.

```
 - Input: List<String>
 - Output: Map<Character,<List<String>>
 - The key of map is 'A' to 'Z'
 - Each list in the map are sorted.
```

### Old Java

```
List<String> keywords = Arrays.asList("Apple", "Ananas", "Mango", "Banana", "Beer"); 
Map<Character, List<String>> result = new HashMap<Character, List<String>>(); 
for(String k : keywords) {   
    char firstChar = k.charAt(0);     
    if(!result.containsKey(firstChar)) {     
        result.put(firstChar, new  ArrayList<String>());   
    }     
    result.get(firstChar).add(k); 
} 
for(List<String> list : result.values()) {   
    Collections.sort(list); 
}
System.out.println(result);
```

### New Java 8

```
List<String> keywords = Arrays.asList("Apple", "Ananas", "Mango", "Banana", "Beer");

Map<Character, List<String>> result = keywords.stream()
     .sorted()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> it.charAt(0)));

System.out.println(result);
```

### New Java 8 with source data already as a 'Stream'

As suggested by @KevinO

```
 Map<Character, List<String>> result = Stream
      .of( "Apple", "Ananas", "Mango", "Banana","Beer")
      .sorted()
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> it.charAt(0)))

System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Just a note: If the list is meant to be used as a stream, then `Stream.of()` can be substituted.

Comment: @KevinO Perhaps you can elaborate. Why don't you post an alternate answer to make your method clear to all.

Comment: not really a new answer, just an alternative that might come in handy. Your Java 8 example would be: `Map<Character, List<String>> result = Stream.of("Apple", "Ananas", "Mango", "Banana", "Beer").sorted().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> it.charAt(0)))`

Comment: @KevinO I see. Good explanation. I wanted to show what happens in the transformation, not really about what the source is , be it a Stream or List or Collection or Iterable or ... If the user has a Stream already, they would not need to call the .stream() method first. Some of us still use lists u know!  A lot of data is and will still come in Lists. But I will integrate your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

With the popular third-party [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) library, compatible with Java 6:

```
TreeMultimap<Character, String> multimap = TreeMultimap.create();
for (String string : list) {
  multimap.put(string.charAt(0), string);
}
return Multimaps.asMap(ImmutableListMultimap.copyOf(multimap));
```

This does deduplicate strings, so an alternate version that allows duplicate strings:

```
ImmutableListMultimap.Builder<Character, String> builder = 
  ImmutableListMultimap.builder();
for (String string : Ordering.natural().sortedCopy(list)) {
  builder.put(string.charAt(0), string);
}
return Multimaps.asMap(builder.build());
```